# Android Eclipse issue

Tags: android, eclipse

I am getting this warning and i am new to android development

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be parameterized    ContentFilesystem.java  /Ultimate/src/org/apache/cordova/file   line 53 Java Problem
Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be parameterized    HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java /CordovaApp-CordovaLib/src/com/squareup/okhttp/internal/http    line 174    Java Problem
Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be parameterized    FileTransfer.java   /Satori2/src/org/apache/cordova/filetransfer    line 820    Java Problem
Dead code   CordovaWebViewClient.java   /Satori2-CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova  line 129    Java Problem
Dead code   CordovaWebViewClient.java   /Satori2-CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova  line 129    Java Problem
Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be parameterized    Capture.java    /Ultimate/src/org/apache/cordova/mediacapture   line 431    Java Problem
Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be parameterized    HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java /Satori2-CordovaLib/src/com/squareup/okhttp/internal/http   line 174    Java Problem
Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be parameterized    FileTransfer.java   /Ultimate/src/org/apache/cordova/filetransfer   line 820    Java Problem
Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be parameterized    ContentFilesystem.java  /Satori2/src/org/apache/cordova/file    line 53 Java Problem
```

what change does it make and how do i solve this. Need some explanation .

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interface declares the method with a raw type Your interface declared a method with raw type so you can not override the method.If you are trying so it will through error.

And in case of dead code you need to share your code then we could able to answer